# Referer is passed from HTTPS to HTTP in some cases... How?

Tags: http, https, http-headers

In theory browsers do not pass on referer information from HTTPS to HTTP sites. And in my experience this has always been true. But I just found an exception, and I want to understand why it works so I can use it as well.

Search for "what is my referer" on https://www.google.ca/
eg: https://www.google.ca/search?q=what+is+my+referer

There are a few sites that will show referer. They all seem to "work" when they shouldn't. For example, click the www.whatismyreferer.com one. I get:

```
 Your referer:
 https://www.google.ca/
```

*Note that sometimes, rarely, I get "no referer" as the result. Go back and click the link again and it'll "work" the next time.*

This should not happen. www.whatismyreferer.com is a non-HTTPS site. The referer header should not be being passed, but it is.

What's going on here, and how can I do the same from my HTTPS site to the HTTP sites I'm linking to?

Comment: I should note that I'm using Chrome on Windows, if that makes any difference (eg: if other people are seeing different results on different browsers / OSs)

Comment: This behaviour is not true any more.

Comment: @ravisorg, Shouldn't this be posted on S/O instead?

Comment: Google now returns an HTTPS link, so the test is no longer valid :-(

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Looks like it's due to a new `<meta>` header that Google is using:

```html
 <meta name="referrer" content="origin">
```

Specification: https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-referrer-policy/

It's currently only [fully supported by a few browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=referrer-policy), so it's not a complete solution, but certainly a start!

Answer (score 4):

This is the standard behavior.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-15.1.3 says

Clients SHOULD NOT include a Referer header field in a (non-secure)
HTTP request if the referring page was transferred with a secure
protocol.

so if your client is doing that, it is violating the standard.

then again, google IS the standard, and they can do whatever they want :-)

Comment: "Should" means optional right?

Comment: yeah, i would think so, optional.

Comment: Since it's optional, Why do you say that it is violating the standard?

Comment: By now 2616 is obsolete. [7231 Section 5.5.2](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-5.5.2) says "A user agent MUST NOT send a Referer header field in an unsecured HTTP request if the referring page was received with a secure protocol." It does not specify what agents are supposed to do for secured HTTP requests though.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be something that the javascript on the google page is doing. I don't see it in firefox with noscript enabled and stop seeing it in Chrome on Windows if I disable javascript. I don't know what specifically as I haven't dug any deeper than that.

Comment: Nope, it's not javascript related (I thought of that and checked it out before asking). Looks like it's a new <meta> tag that Chrome is following.

Comment: Disabling javascript reliably prevents the referrer from working here. I don't know. Maybe more than one thing is involved here.

Comment: That's very interesting - I'm going to experiment more with that. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

`<meta>` 
Label's attribute name has new referrer rules,
Referrer controlling the content of the HTTP Referer HTTP header attached to any request sent from this document.

For more information please check here:
[RFC Referrer Policy](https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-referrer-policy/)

Comment: This is the same as the already accepted answer?!

Answer (score -2):

It is because when you click on the link, you are redirected from https://www.google.... to http://www.google... then you are redirected to www.whatismyreferer.com

And like you said, between http website the referer is transmitted.

You can check that with a [Firefox extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/)

Comment: Are you guessing, or are you basing that on fact? Because I don't see that happening on my end. Clicking the link sends you to an HTTPS redirect on https://www.google.ca/ and then on to the end domain. I never hit a non-https URL until I reach (eg) www.whatismyreferer.com. Also note the referer specifically states httpS://www.google.ca/, not http.

Comment: Yeah, this answer appears to be incorrect.

Comment: Here is the dump of the http headers : http://pastebin.com/Y1HJyJ87

I just stripped resources download (like google suggest & other ajax stuff) and cookies related datas. 

But I have to admit that when I tried multiple times, google behaved differently... Sometimes using only https, therefore not allowing the website to show me my referer. Just try by yourself